# how to get php object to javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a 1 file with html,php and javascript. 
Normally in php you would perform a query like this. This is good and i want to keep.

```
 <?php
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM voedingsmiddelen";
     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
   ?>
```

And then you would use  this php to get the 'name' fields. This outputs "name|age|sex|birthdate|". This part below i want to do in javascript.

```
$count = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result)) {

    $fieldinfo = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result,$count);
    echo $fieldinfo->name;
    $count++;
}
```

This is what i came up with but i get stuck here. I want an alert with 'name' and alert with 'sex' and alert with 'birthdate' from the database.

```
var arraylength=<?php echo sizeof($result)+1; ?>;
        var i=0;
        while(i<arraylength){
            //what goes here i dunno
             alert(idunnohow[i]);

          i++;
        }
```

Is this possible? And how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try encoding your PHP data using `json_encode()`. That's all it takes.

```
var array = <?php echo json_encode( mysqli_fetch_all( $result, MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ) ?>;
```

Comment: what kind of array is this and how do i get things out of there?  alert(array[0]) does not work.

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_all()` is actually replacing the while-loop found in your example: it's returning an array of associative arrays with the latter representing single record of database matching your query. To see the result you might try appending `console.log( array );` after the line given above and see the result for yourself by checking Javascript console of browser. I bet it's an array of objects each containing the fields per record as properties with either field's value.